# Return multiple columns in QComboBox

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, pyside2

I'm using a QComboBox as a delegate in a table for setting a column of the underlying sql table. The combo box is set to a QProxyFilterModel which is then set to a QTableView model, since the information in the combo box exists in another sql table.

What I'd like to do is return multiple columns instead of just one when the combo box is pressed. I know that the way to go is string concatenation but I'm not sure where to implement it.

Since I've subclassed the QTableView, I'm thinking I could create a custom role which concatenates specific columns and returns them to the Proxy model, but I don't know how to pass a role from the proxy model. Do I reimplement method `data` in the proxy model?

Another obvious choice would be to subclass QComboBox and have it concatenate the columns I need but I feel that this is the worse option to choose.

Any ideas on how to implement the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand is that the QComboBox uses a multi-column model and you want the popup to show 2 or more concatenated columns, if so, the easiest option is to establish a custom delegate to the QComboBox.

In the following example, columns 0 and 1 are concatenated, there is also a QTableView whose objective is to show that the model is multi-column:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets


class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        columns = (0, 1)
        text = "\t".join([index.sibling(index.row(), c).data() for c in columns])
        option.text = text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 2)
    for i in range(10):
        it1 = QtGui.QStandardItem("col1-{}".format(i))
        it2 = QtGui.QStandardItem("col2-{}".format(i))
        model.appendRow([it1, it2])

    combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    delegate = Delegate(combo)
    combo.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    combo.setModel(model)

    view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)

    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
    lay.addWidget(combo)
    lay.addWidget(view)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```